# Multithreading in the spring project is not working properly

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to run a function on a complete independent thread wile the rest of my function gets executed for example

```
public void a(){
// do dome work
}

public void b(){
// do dome work
a()
return "hello"
}
```

I need my code to start ruining function a but returns hello without waiting for function a to end

I have tried task executors with spring and @Async annotation but noting is working

```
public static String mainMEthod() {
    asyncMethodWithReturnType();
    return "hello";

}

@Async
public static Future<String> asyncMethodWithReturnType() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Execute method asynchronously - " + 
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return new AsyncResult<String>("hello world !!!!");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //do anything
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the output :

```
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
Execute method asynchronously - main
```

but it should not be running on the main thread

Comment: Are both methods in different classes?

Comment: no they are in the same class, but it is not important i can put them in different classes if it solves the problem

Comment: Async only works when annotating a method of a Spring bean called from outside of that Spring bean. Not for static methods. If you're using static methods, you haven't understood what dependency injection, and thus Spring, is all about.

Comment: To use @Asnc you have to enable it in your spring configuration. And the annotation only works if the method is proxied so it has to be public and invoked from a different class.

Comment: @NielsNet should i enable it in every class where it is used or just in the class with the "@Configuration" annotation?

Comment: Only in the configuration

Answer (score 4):

`@Async` has two limitations:

1. it must be applied to public methods only
2. self-invocation – **calling the async method from within the same class – won’t work**.

The reasons are simple – the method needs to be public so that it can be proxied. And self-invocation doesn’t work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly.

Also make sure to configure correctly:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class SpringAsyncConfig { ... }
```

Read more:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Answer (score 0):

The `@Async` can't be run in a separate thread if the caller is within the same bean.

So option one is to move the `a()` method  to a different bean and call it from `b()`

Or, consider doing what we did in our spring boot project when we needed something similar:

```
public void b() {
  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->  a());
  return "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way Spring add functionalities like `Async` (apart from many others like [this](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring)) is by creating and injecting a proxy which has the logic of providing these functionality.
In your case the call to `asyncMethodWithReturnType` cannot be intercepted by Spring as this is plain java method call without intermediate spring managed proxy. For more information you can check out [here](https://dzone.com/articles/effective-advice-on-spring-async-part-1).